# CSS - VW is being ignored

Tags: html, css, viewport

I am encountering a problem with the vw unit.

I have a slider-wrapper which has a 100vw width. But it seems to ignored.

[image]

On the pictures above, I selected the slider-accomation-wrapper. We can see that there is only the little margin up on the left.
I tried to reduced the width but nothing is happening (I hid the overflow to be sure).

Could it be possible that vw unit is ignored for a reason and what reason?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this element is a `<did>` rather than a `<div>`, so it likely is defaulting to `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: block;`.

Try making it a `<div>` instead of a `<did>`, or add `display: block;` if you intend it to be a `<did>`.